# How to tell credentials used for a Network Mapping?

Tags: windows, networking, security, mappeddrive

I have a networking mapping that doesn't appear to work.  When I connect to the mapping I get access denied when I try to create a folder.

When I created the mapping I told it to login as another account.  I have verified that account has the proper rights on the server side of things.  How can I verify that my local machine is connecting with the right credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you create the mapping?  Via "net use" or using the "Map Network Drive" icon?

If the latter, you should disconnect it and use "net use * \\server\share password /user:domain\username /persistent:yes" from a command-prompt instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take care that you are quoting the password properly if it contains special characters. If it says access denied, have you checked the Event Logs on the system you are trying to connect to for any errors? Verify file permissions as well as share level permissions.